# Angular and radio input not working with ng-model

Tags: angularjs

So I have an Angular project with the following in my directive template

```
<div ng-repeat="poll in polls">
  <div ng-repeat="choice in poll.choices">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" ng-model="userVote" ng-value="choice.text">
                                {{choice.text}}
    <button ng-click="vote(userVote)">Vote!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my controller has the following...

```
 $scope.vote = function(userVote){
  alert(userVote);
 }
```

But the alert says undefined, despite the `{{choice.text}}` showing up properly. There are no JS errors and the other functions in the controller work as expected.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. Can you try to reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: Could be cause I was using a partial from a directive? If so I may need to add that info as well.

Comment: Nope had nothing to do with directives just a Angular Gotcha!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was related to ng-repeat creating its own scope. This does work as expected...

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" ng-model="$parent.userVote" ng-value="choice.text">
```

However, I have also read that the $parent scope is bad practice so I am still researching and the check is still open.

(hope this works)

[Simple Example Failing](http://plnkr.co/edit/oMvPb8nqwIvwxyrvkRpO?p=info)

[Simple Example Passing](http://plnkr.co/edit/ODG5tJjgiINmRnQOseTJ?p=info)

Comment: Your links weren't working when I clicked them, but I think maybe the site is having issues since I couldn't create a new Angular plunk.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know to do when you need to "set" inside an `ng-repeat` (or any directive that creates a new scope) is to, in your controller at the top, do something like:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

And then every `ng-model` that is inside a new scope should have `model.` in front of it.  This will make it so you don't have to use `$parent`.  This has the advantage of, should you add something like `ng-if` somewhere you don't have to do things like `$parent.$parent`.

I suppose if you're using a newer version of angular there's also getters and setters you can use with [`ng-model-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Comment: Great idea! I will add this.